# C++ Template Function Skips a Static function call

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that has static functions that convert basic types to _variant_t type:

```
class VariantConverter {
public:
    static void ToVariant(int Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
        Variant.vt = VT_I4;
        Variant.intVal = Value;
    }

    static void ToVariant(double Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
        Variant.vt = VT_R8;
        Variant.dblVal = Value;
    }

    static void ToVariant(std::string Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
        Variant.SetString(Value.c_str());
    }

    static void ToVariant(bool Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
        Variant.vt = VT_BOOL;
        Variant.boolVal = Value;
    }
};
```

I'm trying to use this in one of my template function as follows:

```
void doSomething(_variant_t);

template <typename T>
void ProcessVariant(T Value) {

    _variant_t Variant;
    VariantConverter::ToVariant(Value, Variant);     // SKIPPED!!!!

    doSomething(Variant);        // Do something with the _variant_t
}


int main() {
    ProcessVariant<int>(1);
    ProcessVariant<double>(1.1);
}
```

The above code wasn't working, so I debugged to find out what was wrong..

And it turned out that the entire line where ToVariant is called is skipped!
(When I set break points to every line and keep hitting "Continue", it just ignores the ToVariant line and directly goes to doSomething)

Why does ToVariant method not get called at all??

Comment: @T.C. Sorry it was a typo. I updated it.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't get called?  What indication (other than a debugger which could be flaky) tells you that the function is skipped?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In visual studio, I set breakpoints at every line in ProcessVariant function... It goes to the first line, and then goes directly to doSomething.. completely ignoring the second line

Comment: Wowowowowowow wait a minute you have 4 methods called the same?

Comment: @Igor Function overloading..?

Comment: Why are you not calling like this: ProcessVariant(<int>1);

Comment: @Igor Have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: @Igor look up function template argument deduction.

Comment: @user2436815 Debugger breakpoints can be weird, especially with optimization enabled. Try adding printing in your `ToVariant` functions instead.

Comment: @Igor You mean what I'm doing in my main() method?

Comment: Yes, why not call ProcessVariant(<int>1);

Comment: Is this in Release mode?

Comment: @Igor what kind of syntax is that...

Comment: @user2436815 - Visual Studio's debugger sometimes goes awry with template code.  That's why you should print something and not rely on the debugger to tell you what's what.

Comment: @user2436815 C syntax ProcessVariant((int)1);

Comment: @user2436815 Imaginary ones. I kinda wish we could downvote comments... Anyway, in Release mode on VS2013, on each call to `ProcessVariant` I hit the breakpoints on the `ToVariant` and `doSomething` lines *twice*.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for your comments. The problem was with release mode in VS.

Comment: @user2436815 - So the program really did work, and it was a "debugger" issue (actually a release mode/debugger issue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MSVC13 this worked fine for me:

```
struct _variant_t {
    int intVal;
    double dblVal;
};

class VariantConverter {
public:
    static void ToVariant(int Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
        //Variant.vt = VT_I4;
        Variant.intVal = Value;
    }

    static void ToVariant(double Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
        //Variant.vt = VT_R8;
        Variant.dblVal = Value;
    }

    //static void ToVariant(std::string Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
    //  Variant.SetString(Value.c_str());
    //}

    //static void ToVariant(bool Value, _variant_t &Variant) {
    //  Variant.vt = VT_BOOL;
    //  Variant.boolVal = Value;
    //}
};

void doSomething(_variant_t){}

template <typename T>
void ProcessVariant(T Value) {

    _variant_t Variant;
    VariantConverter::ToVariant(Value, Variant);     // NOT SKIPPED!!!!

    doSomething(Variant);        // Do something with the _variant_t
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ProcessVariant<int>(1);
    ProcessVariant<double>(1.1);
}
```

If you are using release mode breakpoints can be really weird. The optimizer is getting smarter and smarter, if `doSomething` is in another compilation unit it sometimes figures out that you are not using the argument and therefor doesn't make it.